# Hbase 0.96 integration with Mahout 0.9

Tags: hadoop, hbase, mahout, mahout-recommender, hadoop-plugins

Is it possible to use H base version 0.96 as data source for Mahout 0.9 version?

Example :- Running Mahout on a Hbase Table.

I am using system having configurations:- Ubuntu 14.04 -64 bit architecture. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From you tags I assume you are asking about the Mahout recommenders.

You can write code to take in the matrix of all items by all users, either as a dense or sparse matrix (dense has 0 where no preference strength exists and sparse would omit any 0 value)

Here are some slide describing using Hbase with Mahout : http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/hbasecon-2013-using-apache-hbase-for-large-matrices